# News and article management plugin install for Zencart

Tags: plugins, e-commerce, zen-cart

I wanted to know the step for installing news and article management plugin to my Zencart website. I am a newbie in zencart so I need to resolve this issue step by step. So please explain with screenshots if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope [News and Article Manager & Optional Sideboxes](http://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=791) will help you in installing news and article management plugin to your zencart website.

Comment: I tried with this but I am not getting which folder files where to place and also when I am installing SQL patches through admin, then I am getting this error - WARNING: An error occurred, please refresh the page and try again.